# Php Server Monitor can not be found

Tags: server, apache2, php, error-handling

I'm using phpservermon 3.2.0, and today when accessing it, it appeared as 404 not found and these two lines

'''
The requested URL /phpservermon/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 172.20.41.192 Port 80
'''

the url is this one http://172.20.41.192/phpservermon/

also here is my config file

```
<?php
define('PSM_DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('PSM_DB_PORT', '3306');
define('PSM_DB_NAME', 'phpmonitordb');
define('PSM_DB_USER', 'phpmonitoruser');
define('PSM_DB_PASS', 'phpmonitorpwd');
define('PSM_DB_PREFIX', 'psm_');
define('PSM_BASE_URL', 'http://172.20.41.192/phpservermon');
define('PSM_DEUG', true);
```

I have no clue why it's not finding it yesterday I was accessing it easily.

Comment: What changed since the last time it was working? Did you upgrade any package? did you upgrade the OS? etc.

Comment: I installed LAMP and then was working on an website, but I've been checking the LAMP files and can't find nothing that could make that happen, and I already had php and mysql, I just installed apache.